# How to restore a window configuration after reboot?

Tags: window, window-configuration

I have foo.txt on the left and a terminal on the right:

```
|-------|----------|
|foo.txt|ansi@term>|
|-------|----------|
```

How can I restore the layout of the windows with the same buffers displayed after reboot?

I'v installed https://github.com/ffevotte/desktop-plus and tried `desktop+-load` after `desktop+-create` which doesn't restore nor inform what's happening.

System Info :computer:

- OS: gnu/linux
- Emacs: 26.3
- Spacemacs: 0.300.0
- Spacemacs branch: develop
- Graphic display: t
- Distribution: spacemacs
- Editing style: vim
- Completion: helm

Comment: Try out [`winner-mode`](https://irreal.org/blog/?p=1557) and see if that's what you need.

Comment: Thank you, I must restore the windows and buffers after each reboot which I could not find as a winner-mode feature

Answer (score 1):

You could try [psession package](https://github.com/thierryvolpiatto/psession).  I find it  fills exactly my needs.

In your init file :

```
(psession-mode 1)
   ;; For saving minibuffer history,  as a replacement of savehist-mode.
   (psession-savehist-mode 1)
   ;; to save periodically (autosave) your emacs session,
   (psession-autosave-mode 1)
```

Best, 
Samusz