# Restore window configuration in a different frame

Tags: frames, registers, window-configuration

I sometimes save my window configuration with `C-x r w`, and restore with `C-x r j`.  However I can't restore the window configuration in a different frame.  Is there a way to do this?

**NB:** I found [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/56194/how-to-restore-a-window-configuration-after-reboot) question about saving window configuration across restarts, but that's not what I'm looking for.  I am still in the same Emacs session, however in a different frame.

Comment: Well, I looked at it and am not sure it's possible unless you add such functionality. `C-x r j` basically runs a wrapper around [this func](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/1ea3b369021c90701c634c512426f75ce1291d77/src/window.c#L7100). It type-casts the arg to a custom `struct save_window_data`, so you can't edit it from ELISP unless there are getters/setters defined, of which I found none. As a side-note, to prevent confusion: there's an arg `DONT-SET-FRAME` but it doesn't do what you're interested in, instead it simply decides what frame focus will be given after config is restored.

Comment: @Hi-Angel thanks a lot for taking a deep dive, and pointing me in the right direction. This has been bothering me for many yrs. I've contributed to Emacs before, but never to the C code base. Maybe this is an opportunity :-p